# Парсер для Анимедиа Версия 0.2

Tags: python, csv, bs4, lxml, grequests

Немного переделал парсер по очень хорошему совету, добавил grequests, скорость значительно увеличилась, но возникли другие проблемы!

1. Собираются не все ссылки по аниме их примерно 1645, а собираются лишь 1100.
2. на get_text() ругается.

```
    import grequests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import lxml
    import csv

    pages = []
    for i in range(1,95): 
        page = 
    "https://amedia.online/anime/"
        page = page + f"page/{i}/"
        pages.append(page)
    rs = (grequests.get(item) for item in pages)
    resp = grequests.imap(rs,grequests.Pool(10))
    links = []
    for r in resp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        divb = soup.find_all("div",class_="c1-item")
        for d in divb:
            a = d.find("a").get("href")
            links.append(a)
    rs2 = (grequests.get(urls) for urls in links)
    resp2 = grequests.imap(rs2, grequests.Pool(10))
    allData = set()
    pg = 0
    for r2 in resp2:
        s = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'lxml')
        pg += 1
        print(f"[INFO] Собранна {pg} страница")
        title = s.find("h1").text.replace("смотреть онлайн\n", "")
        descr = s.find("div",class_="full-text film-desc clearfix").get_text(strip=True)
        ep = s.find("div",class_="info").get_text(strip=True)[25:30].replace("-","").replace("с","").replace("се","").replace("е","")
        itog = s.find("div", class_="multirating-itog").get_text(strip=True).replace("Итоговая оценка:","")[:4]
        year = s.find("div", class_="fi-desc").text  
       allData.add((str(title),str(ep), str(year), str(itog), str(descr)))
    with open("AnimediaData.csv",'w') as f:
            fcsv = csv.writer(f)
            fcsv.writerows(allData)
```

Comment: Наверное проблема в том, что вы думаете синхронно. Попробуйте для начала многопоточность, а там до асихронности недалеко. Тоже поначалу не понимал эту асинхроность.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую.

Comment: Гляньте библиотеку grequests, думаю вам она подойдет